# HTML/CSS List inline overlay color of next element

Tags: html, css

I have a header. It have grey `background-color`. Active and hover element have `background-color` white too. On `hover` element I add `box-shadow`. But, if second element is active and I will hover on first element, `box-shadow` will go under second element. (`z-index` is not helping). Any ideas?

Here is a snippet.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

ul li:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.active,
ul li:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li class="active">Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Let me know if that question doesn't answer you.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I didn't like negative shadow, as I see it was much easier to add `position: relative;` and `z-index` to elements.